# We can't migrate reCaptcha enterprise v1beta1 to v1 smooth

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

Now my website is running with reCaptcha enterprise v1beta1 for assessments.create.
These days,I worked with this feature for migrating reCaptcha enterprise v1beta1 to v1.

This is guide. https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/migration-v1

After update with this guide,when I tested it whith some error.

`{\n    \\\"code\\\": 403,\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"Permission denied for: recaptchaenterprise.assessments.create. Please ensure you have sufficient permissions: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access\\\",\n    \\\"status\\\": \\\"PERMISSION_DENIED\\\"\n  }\n}\n\"","Response":"{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 403,\n    \"message\": \"Permission denied for: recaptchaenterprise.assessments.create. Please ensure you have sufficient permissions: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access\",\n    \"status\": \"PERMISSION_DENIED\"\n  }`

So aslo need some permission set with the update.

If we update it and set some permissions for it, will the current v1betal be affected?

What is best practice,create a new sitekey with v1?